# Tag's id instead of name in links, wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, taxonomy

I'm using taxonomy to make database. All links with tag's name. Is it possible to make tag use their id in links?

In function.php i use this

```
register_taxonomy( 'game', 'post', array( 'hierarchical' => false, 'label' => __('Game', 'series'), 'query_var' => 'game', 'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'Games' ) ) );
```

in page

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'game', 'Games: ', ', ', '' ); ?>
```

Right now links look like
http://***.com/games/clash-of-clans/

I need them look like
http://***.com/games/123/

Answer (score 0):

In your permalinks settings use the numeric structure. See [Using Permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks).

Alternatively you can use `Custom Structure` and use `%category%/%post_id%` in the field.